# How to add checkbox to stwe/DatatablesBundle for symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, datatables

I am using https://github.com/stwe/DatatablesBundle for my symfony2 application. It's still buggy but works great. Now I want in my table I have id, name for the id. I want to add check box so that I can select them by their id. I've searched enough but couldn't find any solution. Can anyone help me how can I add check box to the column id as select?

One thing : my 'serverSide': false.

```
 $this->columnBuilder
        ->add("id", "column", array("title" => "Id","type" => "checkbox",))
        ->add("name", "column", array("title" => "Name",))
```

this is my code for generating the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I found the solution, im not sure if this is the best way to solve the problem but still i can workout my issue.

```
->add(null, "multiselect", array(
            "attributes" => array(
                "name" => "check",                ),
            "actions" => array(
                array(
                    "route" => "artist_show",
                    "route_parameters" => array(
                        "id" => "id"
                    ),
                    "label" => "Select",
                    )
        )))
```

adding the multi select option solve the necessity of have a check box